# C# cookie not read in java script

Tags: c#-4.0, cookies

I have code which throws runtime exception - 'Could not find file' after this exception,cookie is set using `httpContext.Response.AppendCookie('testCookie','true')`.Now when reading cookie in java script using `document.cookie('testCookie')` return empty string.Can any one know the reason for this issue ?

Comment: You can refer a good article [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) about cookie